# Unit Testing Android SQLIte

Tags: android, sqlite, unit-testing, junit, robolectric

I want to write Unit tests for the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class in my Android app.

I need the test project to use a separate database for test purpose.

Please suggest whether:

1. I should use plain Android JUnit for unit testing?
2. I should use RoboElectric for unit testing?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for option 3 - use instrumentation testing for this. The robolectric shadow implementation of SQLite is not the same as on the devices and so you can step into nasty s**** ( been there done that )

Comment: So could u please suggest me some tutorial or any link so that I can understand how to implement unit tests of SQLIte using instrumentation testing.Thanks!

Comment: I want some specific implemenation of SQLite unit testing using the instrumentation testing.The link you gave is the android developer unit testing link.I want a bit more streamlined reply.Thanks!